# R code became slow

Tags: r, performance

I am having problem with the time execution in R, I did the following to identify if something is repeated for category, and have unique identifier for all categories. So the data looks like:

```
CAT       IDCAT     COUNTR    IDUNIQUE
categ1    fffss     1         1
categ2    ffaab     2         2
categ3    fffss     3         1
categ1    ffaab     4         2
categ3    mmmaa     5         5
categ2    aaamm     6         6
categ3    ffaab     7         2
```

The code that i use was:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Table)){
  Table$IDUNIQUE[Table$IDCAT[i]==Table$IDCAT]<-min(Table$COUNTR[Table$IDCAT[i]==Table$IDCAT])
}
```

The rule is just identify the IDCAT repeated by CAT, to have an unique id for all CAT, if the IDCAT is repeated in CAT so IDUNIQUE it's going to have the same value where IDCAT will be equal.
I have approximately 1,200,000 registers, so, when i ran the code for 20,000 register the time of execution was of 15 minutes approximately, now i ran the code and the time for 100 registers was of 9 minutes, i don't know why it is so slow, someone could help me to solve this? Or someone know if there is some function or function to make the code faster?

Comment: so you are trying find and label rows that repeat the values in columns `IDCAT` and `CAT`?

Comment: Your performance issues are due to explicit indexing. If you would use vectorized operations in functional manner it would make the execution faster. Further more, using libraries and approaches from `dplyr` or `data.table` even further would accelerate your data wrangling

Comment: try to write down the rule that will lead you to determine that a row is unique, please. edit your post with that info. As @Drey says, vectors are your friend here. I'm also thinking that you might be able to label the frame a single vector op, but I'm also reading from the table that you really are only labelling a row with `IDUNIQUE` if they have the same `IDCAT`

Comment: i have tried to solve the problem with dplyr functions but i have not achieved solve the problem, i don't know if some one of you have solved some problem like this, wold be very helpfull if you have some explicit solution to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you're trying to do, is find the minimum value for the `COUNTR` column, for each level of `IDCAT`, and create a column from this.  The function `ave` does this:

```
> with(Table, ave(COUNTR, IDCAT, FUN=min))
[1] 1 2 1 2 5 6 2
```

Assign this to `Table$IDUNIQUE` to finish the work.

This is not any lower in complexity than what you have, but the work is done  largely in C code, rather than looping in R.